# Como cargar configuración de base de datos al iniciar la aplicación

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Hola estoy trabajando con 2 base de datos, una es local en el servidor y la otra es en un servidor externo, cuando me logueo  lo hago por la app_1 que es la local y después configuro la conexión de la otra base de datos app_2, realice algo parecido a lo que explican  [Django multiple and dynamic databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585373/django-multiple-and-dynamic-databases) lo hice pero no me funciona me dice que la base de datos no existe y al ponerla en setting.py me  funciona que puede ser dejo como tengo todo.
Mi archivo guardarconfiguracion.py

```
def save_db_settings_to_file(form):
 path_to_store_settings = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,  'SystemProyect')
 for fname in os.listdir(path_to_store_settings):
  if fname=='conexion.py':
    full_path = os.path.join(path_to_store_settings, fname)
    remove(full_path)

database_id = 'app_2'  # just something unique
newDatabase = {}
newDatabase["id"] = database_id
newDatabase['ENGINE'] = 'sql_server.pyodbc'
newDatabase['NAME'] = form.data['database']
newDatabase['USER'] = form.data['usuario_sql']
newDatabase['PASSWORD'] = form.data['password_sql']
newDatabase['HOST'] = form.data['servidor_sql']
newDatabase['PORT'] = ''
settings.DATABASES[database_id] = newDatabase

newDbString = """DATABASES={'%(id)s':{
'ENGINE': '%(ENGINE)s', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or    'oracle'.
'NAME': '%(NAME)s',                      # Or path to database file if   using sqlite3.
'USER': '%(USER)s',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
'PASSWORD': '%(PASSWORD)s',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
'HOST': '%(HOST)s',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
'OPTIONS':"{'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0',}"
} }
 """% newDatabase
file_to_store_settings = os.path.join(path_to_store_settings, 'conexion' + ".py")
salvar=open(file_to_store_settings,'w')
salvar.write(newDbString)
salvar.close()
```

así es como guarda en el archivo conexion.py

```
DATABASES = {
'app_2': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'prueba',  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'pepe',  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '123456',  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '10.16.41.2',  # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',  # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    'OPTIONS': "{'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0',}"
}
```

}

y para cargar la configuración tengo un `import  settings_manager` en settings.py  que se encuentra en el archivo settings_manager.py

```
import os
path_to_store_settings =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))),  'SystemProyect')
for fname in os.listdir(path_to_store_settings):
  if fname == 'conexion.py':
   full_path = os.path.join(path_to_store_settings, fname)
  with open(full_path) as fobj:
    archivo_inicio = fobj.read()
exec(archivo_inicio)
```

Answer (score 0):

Haz lo siguiente, al settings.py cambiale el nombre a base.py, crea dos archivos mas uno local.py y otro remote.py, en el archivo base.py quita la configuracion de la base de datos, en el archivo local.py pon lo siguiente:

> `from .base import *
>   DEBUG = True
>   DATABASES={
>       'default':{
>           'ENGINE':''django.db.backends.sqlite3',
>           'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
>       }
>   }`
>   
>   en el archivo remote.py haz lo mismo pero poniendo la configuracion de la base de datos remota, es decir la configuracion remota que tienes en el archivo conexion.py, te quedaria asi:
>   
>   `from .base import *
>   DATABASES = {
>   'app_2': {
>       'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
>       'NAME': 'prueba',
>       'USER': 'pepe',
>
>       'PASSWORD': '123456', 
>       'HOST': '10.16.41.2',
>
>       'PORT': '',
>
>       'OPTIONS': "{'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0',}"
>   }`
>
> y luego a la hora de leer la confiuracion hazlo asi, corre esto en la terminal, suponiendo que estas en la ruta hacia tu proyecto
>   `python manage.py runserver --settings=settings.local`, ahdebes crear ambos archivos en la carpeta settings, solo para llamr otra configuracion debes solo cambiar la que quieres, algo asi, `python manage.py runserver --settings=settings.remote`, espero funcione

Comment: Eso es si voy a utilizar una base de datos y despues la otra, pero para utilizar las 2 base de datos al mismo tiempo

Comment: revisa esto http://www.forosdelweb.com/f130/django-usar-multiples-bd-crearlos-con-modelos-1134267/

Comment: por lo que veo no entiendes mi pregunta

Comment: en mi settings.py tengo configurado 2 base de datos pero la de app_2 esta en un fichero que se guarda cuando por el visual el usuario pone los datos de la base de datos usuario passw  host y base de datos eso es guardado en un fichero que es el que me hace falta cargar cuando inicie el servidor junto con la otra base de datos que es la principal que tiene los usuarios para acceder al sistema

Comment: ahora si entiendo, lo siento hermano, nunca he hecho eso, por lo que veo estas buscando en los directorios si aparece el archivo guardado, y luego tratas de abrirlo para usarlo, si encuentro algo te comento

Comment: esta bien gracias

Comment: Tambien has montado ya un servidor sin virtualenv con apache he visto muchos tutoriales pero no doy como es , el problema es como apache inicia el servidor django

Comment: no no he hecho montado ninguno

Answer (score 0):

prueba esto, y configura cada una con lo que lleva

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'production',
        'USER': 'secret',
        'PASSWORD': 'secret',
    },
    'otra': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'history',
        'USER': 'secret',
        'PASSWORD': 'secret',
    }
}`